# Is there a way to rename Model columns in Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent, lumen

I have a database that is in spanish, example:

```
create table usuarios
(
    idUsuario int(6) unsigned zerofill not null auto_increment
        primary key,
    estado enum('A', 'B') default 'A' not null,
    nombre varchar(60) not null,
    correo varchar(60) not null,
    clave varchar(32) not null,
    fecha_alta datetime not null,
    fecha_baja datetime null
)
comment 'Usuarios que consumen la API'
;

create index estado
    on usuarios (estado)
;
```

I have the following model in Lumen:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable;

  protected $connection = 'api';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

  protected $table = 'usuarios';

  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'correo',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
//    protected $hidden = [
//        'clave',
//    ];
}
```

So what's the problem? This works... but I need all the API in english, that includes parameters... but in this case Lumen only understands when the create, and update method receives the parameters in spanish. Is there a way to map the `$filleable = ['nombre', 'correo']` as I did with the `$table = 'usuarios'`? I was hoping something like `$filleable = ['nombre' => 'name', 'correo' => 'email']` would do the trick but I did not see anything in the documenation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Eloquent resources would be a perfect fit for this, but I think they're not part of Lumen. You could make accessors that have English names and return content from Spanish named columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible. Use [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).

For example, to get the **name** attribute from database, define an accessor:

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->nombre;
}
```

To update **name** attribute to database, define a mutator:

```
public function setNameAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['nombre'] = $value;
}
```

After defining accessors & mutators, to access and update the **name** attribute as follows:

```
$name = $user->name; // access the field nombre
$user->name = 'foo';
$user->save(); // update nombre field
```

Comment: Thanks @ben that did the trick. Additionally I had to redefine the `toArray()` method of my model to make it show the json response in english aswell